# Different behavior of lifecycle hooks between Vue and Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have two pages foo and bar, I print a message to the console when each of the hooks works. In vue it's one order, in nuxt it's another

**Vue:**

enter /foo

```
beforeCreate
created
beforeMount
mounted
```

switch /foo to /bar

```
beforeCreate
created
beforeMount
beforeDestroy
destroyed
mounted
```

**Nuxt:**

enter /foo

```
beforeCreate
created
beforeMount 
mounted
```

switch /foo to /bar

```
beforeDestroy
destroyed
beforeCreate
created
beforeMount
mounted
```

When there is a transition to /foo, then in vue/nuxt the hooks fire in the same order, but if you switch from route to route, then the order will change. Why is this happening? Maybe I’m doing something wrong?

[Sandbox Vue](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-khorana-zbddxb) 
[Sandbox Nuxt](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-mountain-u1q5p6)

Comment: This is probably because of the [`mode` set by default](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/transition#object) by Nuxt? This is probably not the default one in Vue. Also, maybe check the [Nuxt lifecycle](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle#nuxt-lifecycle), not sure if it can help anyhow.

Comment: @kissu, thanks, problem solved after changing transition.mode to in-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default transition mode](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/transition/#object) of Nuxt is

```js
export default {
  transition: {
    mode: 'out-in'
  }
}
```

try changing it to

```js
export default {
  transition: {
    mode: 'in-out'
  }
}
```